# Getting Null Contact id when querying with account name in Raw Contacts in Android

Tags: android, android-contacts

```
   private void displayAllContactsByType(String accountName) {
        Cursor rawCursor = null;

        try {
            rawCursor = mCProviderClient.query(
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME + "= ?",
                    new String[]{accountName},
                null);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int contactIdColumn = rawCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID);


        Utils.Log("Raw Size", " " + rawCursor.getCount());

        while (rawCursor.moveToNext()) {


            String contactId = rawCursor.getString(contactIdColumn);

           // Utils.Log("contactId ",contactId);
            storeContactDetails(contactId);
        }

        if (contactList != null) {


            contactListener = (ContactListener) context;
            contactListener.updateView(contactList);

        }

    }
```

I am getting all the account name which raw contacts contain. And I would like to get all the contacts belongs to the particular account name but I am getting null contact id. How can I get all the contact id to a particular account name and then respective data of that contact id along with it?

Comment: Where is your `contactList` initialised?

Comment: it is initialized properly. I mean globally and I get null over here                             String contactId = rawCursor.getString(contactIdColumn);

Comment: I rarely use cursors so I may be wrong, but is it not because you move next without checking that there is something next? Try `while (rawCursor.isAfterLast() == false)` instead of `while (rawCursor.moveToNext())` as suggested [here](http://www.higherpass.com/android/tutorials/accessing-data-with-android-cursors/2/)

Comment: @Eselfar no, moveToNext will return true if it was able to move to the next item, the while loop is ok

Answer (score 3):

First, `RawContacts.CONTACT_ID` is of type `Long`, not `String`, so you should do:

```
Long contactId = rawCursor.getLong(contactIdColumn);
```

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#CONTACT_ID don't pay attention to the type of the `CONTACT_ID` field which are always Strings, look at `Type: INTEGER` below it.

Second, this is rare, but can happen when a `RawContact` does not belong to any `Contact`, I call those zombie `RawContacts`, they can be created either via a corrupt DB or a bug, or intentionally using [`AGGREGATION_MODE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsColumns.html#AGGREGATION_MODE) when creating the `RawContact`, see [`AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContacts.html#AGGREGATION_MODE_DISABLED)

Comment: I agree with your second point but how to avoid zombie RawContacts.

Comment: you can't avoid them, in my experience zombies exist on ~20% of devices, mostly because of bugs in SyncAdapters (not in your control). You can simply skip RawContacts in your code that don't have valid `CONTACT_ID`, as they aren't visible to the user anyway

Comment: One more thing it that count=rawCursor.getCount() gives proper count like say i have selected Sim 1 as  Account name and i get the count as 7  but I only gets 6 contacts in my list similar happens with other account too i get less number of contacts compare to the count in above code. pls suggest